# NSKeyedArchiver init not called

Tags: objective-c, init, nskeyedarchiver

I used the following code and it throws an error **[NSKeyedArchiver init]: cannot use -init for initialization**

Code:-

```
NSKeyedArchiver *a=[[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the NSKeyedArchiver class doesn't have "plain vanilla" init method.  you have to use initForWritingWithMutableData:

Comment: But, its super class which is NSObject has that method

Comment: If you look at the NSObject docs, it says: "The init method defined in the NSObject class does no initialization; it simply returns self"  Subclasses are supposed to implement their own init methods

Comment: Also, I think some classes have private init methods that just call the class's designated initializer with some default values.  Maybe NSKeyedArchiver doesn't have one.  For instance, you can initialize an NSView with init instead of initWithFrame:, and it will give you a view with a zeroRect, so I'm guessing that internally, NSView calls initWithFrame:NSZeroRect when you initialize with init.

Comment: Most likely, `NSKeyedArchiver` calls `[self doesNotRecognizeSelector: _cmd]` in its `init` implementation, but it calls `[super init]` in its designated initializer. At least, that's how I would enforce using the designated initializer.